# Co-Worker nags about another employee

Tags: coworking

I sit next to a coworker of mine. We are on the same team. However, he nags all the time about this other employee who is in the other department.

I am frustrated him talking everyday at least once. What should I do? Right now I just ignore the talk and continue with my work.

Comment: Hi RG-3, right now your question appears [off-topic](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2696#2696) since it reads like a rant and simply asks "What do I do?" You might consider rewording to make your question more answerable.

Comment: Purely as a matter of English "nag" is when someone makse criticisms of you to you, especially trying to get you to do something differently. I believe the English word you are looking for is "gripe" ("whinge" if you are Australian).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell him you aren't interested in the conversation.  Politely, but repeatedly if need be.

Ignoring him, or giving him generic nods of confirmation and token acknowledgement, are only going to feed into your co-worker's desire to gossip and complain.  State clearly and plainly that you are not interested in hearing about this gossip.  Point out that you would like to get back to work, or continue to eat lunch, or whatever you are doing at the time that you would rather be doing when he tries to engage you in conversation.

**Be Polite** though, no matter what.  He is your co-worker, and you have to work with him even if he is being a bother.

If it starts to interfere with your workflow, and he refuses to stop, consult your supervisor in private.  Explain that the constant distractions are getting in the way of work (don't bring up the conversation topic - that's irrelevant) and ask to be assigned to a different seat.